# python: Убывание числа с каждым запросом

Tags: python, telebot

Мне нужно чтобы когда пользователь вводил запрос, писались числа с 10 до 0 в порядке убывания (с каждым запросом), но как это воплотить?

```
if message.text == 'Работать':
        mon = int(10000)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы заработали ' + str(mon) + '$!\nЭнергия: ' + '??????' , parse_mode='html')
```

Должно быть так:
запрос -> пишется число 10 -> запрос -> пишется число 9 и так до 0.
И чтобы каждые 5 минут добавлялось по 1 (до 10).
Помогите пожалуйста, я не справляюсь!

Comment: число одно на всех или для каждого своё?

Comment: @Интик, каждому свое

Comment: Вообще, хорошо бы иметь полный код. Но так могу предположить, что можно создавать какую-нибудь переменную/использовать массив при появлении нового ID пользователя, но если данное ID уже "зарегистрированно", то с каждым запросом пользователя от его энергии вычитайте единицу.

Answer (score 0):

```py
counter = 10 #Счетчик
while (counter > -1):
    input("->") #Ввод
    print(counter) #Вывол значения счётчика
    counter = counter - 1 #Уменьшение значения счётчика на 1
print("Счётчик равен 0. Программа завершается!")
```

Как сделать чтобы каждые 5 минут этот счётчик восполнялся на единицу, я, увы, не имею понятия!